# NSOperation completionBlock retain cycle warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsoperation, retain-cycle

I have similar code in two parts of my app, xcode gives the warning for one but not the other. From my understanding of the documentation I think there should be no warning in either case.

```
// In one part of my code I have this
__block UploadOperation *uploadOperation = [[UploadOperation alloc] initWithPsc:self.persistentStoreCoordinator webService:self.webService];
uploadOperation.completionBlock = ^{
    if (uploadOperation.uploadCount > 0) {
        self.expediteNextSync = YES;
    }
};

// And in another I have this
__block SyncOperation *syncOperation = [[SyncOperation alloc] initWithPsc:self.persistentStoreCoordinator webService:self.webService];
syncOperation.completionBlock = ^{
    if (syncOperation.expediteNextSync) { // <--- This one gives the warning "Capturing 'syncOperation' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle"
        ...
    }
};
```

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperation/1408085-completionblock?language=objc) says:

> In iOS 8 and later and macOS 10.10 and later, this property is set to
>   nil after the completion block begins executing.

So I don't think there will be any retain cycle.